# EF: Fetching Object containing a list as property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following classes:

```
public class DbCatalogEntry
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    private string filename;
    public long size { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public string vcodec { get; set; }
    public List<CatalogAudioStreamEntry> audiostreams { get; set; }
    public string imdbId { get; set; }
    public int ownedByUser { get; set; }
    public string mxHash { get; set; }
}


public class CatalogAudioStreamEntry
{
    public int bitrate { get; set; }
    public string codec { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public int channels { get; set; }
    public string features { get; set; }
}
```

This is a one to many relationship. I am trying to retrieve a list of `DbCatalogEntry` objects from the database and also filling the `audiostreams` in the same query.

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
var MovieEntryList = 
    (from vwCat in ctx.sp_GetMovieCatalog(getCurrentUserId())
      select new DbCatalogEntry()
          {
              id = vwCat.id,
              size = vwCat.size,
              duration = vwCat.duration,
              vcodec = vwCat.codec,
              Filename = vwCat.filename,
              imdbId = vwCat.imdb_id,
              mxHash = vwCat.mxhash,
              ownedByUser = (int)vwCat.owned,
              width = vwCat.width,
              height =  vwCat.height,
              audiostreams = 
                (from astr in ctx.audiostreamentry
                  where astr.movie_id == vwCat.id
                  select new CatalogAudioStreamEntry()
                      {
                          bitrate = astr.bitrate,
                          channels = astr.channels,
                          codec = astr.codec,
                          features = astr.features,
                          language = astr.language
                      }).ToList()
          }).ToList();
```

Search revealed that you cannot put a ToList() into a linq to entity query as it cannot be converted converted. I read multiple suggestions about changing `audiostreams` to IEnumerable but was not able to get this to work either. Most attempts compiled fine but faild during runtime with *Unable to create a constant value of type...*

Can anyone point me to the correct direction to solve this issue? The important thing is that the round trips to the database must be kept at a minimum so it would not be possible to create a client-side subquery for each `DbCatalogEntry` to fill the list.

**Update #1:**

To provide more details: This is the model that was generated by EF from my database:
[image: Model]

`sp_GetMovieCatalog(getCurrentUserId())`  is a stored function on the SQL server which accepts one parameter which is used to filter the results.

What I want to do is selecting from `movieenty` and load all associated rows from `audiostreamenty`.
This data should be used to create instances of `DbCatalogEntry`, so the result type would be `List<DbCatalogEntry>`.

Is that possible at all? Maybe there is a better/easier solution?

Comment: Do you using EF CodeFirst or ModelFirst?

Comment: Well I am just starting with EF and I designed the Database before independently and then added it via *generate model from database* so if I understand it correctly it would be Database First

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you have your problem, because trying to use same context for multiple queries

You can try it this way:

```
    var MovieEntryList = 
    (from vwCat in ctx.sp_MovieCatalog
    where vwCat.owned = currentUserId
    select new DbCatalogEntry()
      {
          id = vwCat.id,
          size = vwCat.size,
          duration = vwCat.duration,
          vcodec = vwCat.codec,
          Filename = vwCat.filename,
          imdbId = vwCat.imdb_id,
          mxHash = vwCat.mxhash,
          ownedByUser = (int)vwCat.owned,
          width = vwCat.width,
          height =  vwCat.height,
          audiostreams = vwCat.audiostreamentry.Select(astr=>
               new CatalogAudioStreamEntry()
                  {
                      bitrate = astr.bitrate,
                      channels = astr.channels,
                      codec = astr.codec,
                      features = astr.features,
                      language = astr.language
                  }).ToList()
      }).ToList();
```

Or this way:

```
    var MovieEntryList = ctx.audiostreamentry.where(p=>p.movieCatolog.ownedByUser - currentUserId)
    //.ToList() //if you call ToList() here futher will be LINQ to Object, and you want have most of problems
    .GroupBy(p=>new {Id = p.movieCatolog.id, Owner = p.movieCatolog.p.movieCatolog.id})
    .Select(p=> new DbCatalogEntry{
    id = p.Key.Id,
    ownedByUser = p.Key.Owner,
    audiostrams = p.Select(x=>new CatalogAudioStreamEntry
    {
                      bitrate = astr.bitrate,
                      channels = astr.channels,
                      codec = astr.codec,
                      features = astr.features,
                      language = astr.language
                  })

    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Eventually I got it to work, however there were a few addiontal steps: I used a TVS which apparently cannot be used in EF so that had to be converted to a stored procedure. The SP had to be manually added to the model as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486350/stored-procedure-into-entity-framework-model