# Lat & Long Geography Radius Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, t-sql, c#-4.0, sqlgeography

I am trying to find the stores within X radius of a users lat & long. I have read quite a few questions, answers, and articles on the topic. My results don't have to be pin point accurate but false positives as you might get with the filter on a Geography column would not be acceptable.

Given the above requirements I don't see the need to use the Geography data type and add a spatial index. I also don't need a perfect circle radius. In other words a bounding box would be acceptable. So I settled on this [solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/38b7f743-4f65-4920-b0dc-219787fab3df/querying-points-within-a-radius-of-point-x) from Alastaira who has a very informative session on the topic [here.](http://www.sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event5/Creating_High_Performance_Spatial_Databases)

Now my application is MVC using CF EF4 and SQL 2008R2. I was originally thinking to do the operation in LINQ like I would any other db interaction but I was honestly stumped at a few steps such as:

```
DECLARE @point geography = geography::Point(40.7316, -73.9920, 4326);
```

I don't think EF4 supports the geography data type so that would certainly complicate things.

Then I started thinking...given that the db is kinda geared for this kind of crunching should I just wrap the TSQL in a SP that spits out a recordset I can then use LINQ on?

This is my first spatial db operation so any ideas or suggestions are welcome and would be appreciated.

If the sp is a viable solution suggestions for the best way to implement would be great.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't think EF4 supports the geography data type so that would certainly complicate things.

Entity Framework 4.x does not natively support geography.

> If the sp is a viable solution suggestions for the best way to implement would be great.

[Using stored procedures to return stronly typed objects has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486350/stored-procedure-into-entity-framework-model).  It should be straight forward enough to create a stored procedure to deal with the geography datatype but not include that specific type in the result entity objects.